# Download an audio through http and store in a local folder in c#

Tags: c#, http, audio

Can anyone share me a piece of code in c# that i can download an audio file of .wmv format using http request and store in a local folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use web client.

```
using System.Net;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/myfile.wmv", @"c:\myfile.wmv");
```

using http web request

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/myfile.wmv");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv"; 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream();

byte[] inBuf = new byte[response.ContentLength];
int bytesToRead = (int)inBuf.Length;
int bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesToRead > 0)
{
    int n = reader.Read(inBuf, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
    if (n == 0)
    break;
    bytesRead += n;
    bytesToRead -= n;
}
FileStream fstr = new FileStream(@"c:\myfile.wmv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                     FileAccess.Write);
fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead);
reader.Close();
fstr.Close();
```